# How can i access to a textfield in other jframe with java?

Tags: java, netbeans

i'm bigginer in java .
i tried to make a button in jframe1 and a textfield in jframe2 
So i want to the button while clicking on it write a text in the textfield in the jframe2
Please help me and thanks.
i traied this:

```
String adress = jTextField1.getText(); //in the first jframe1
```

Comment: Show us how you tried to do it. Post your code.

Comment: done. the code above

Comment: You probably need a reference to there other Frame in your current Frame or whatever...

Comment: No what you need is, inside the `actionPreformed()` of your button `ActionListener` set the text of the text field you want to whatever.

For a more specific answer it will help if you post all of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example(if I understood your question correctly):

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Intro {

    static int count = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException
                | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        final JFrame frame1 = new JFrame("frame 1");
        final JFrame frame2 = new JFrame("frame 2");
        final JButton button = new JButton("Button");
        final JTextField textFieald = new JTextField("0");

        button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 40));
        button.setFocusable(false);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                textFieald.setText(Integer.toString(++count));
            }
        });

        frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame1.getContentPane().add(button);
        frame1.pack();
        frame1.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame1.setVisible(true);

        frame2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame2.getContentPane().add(textFieald);
        frame2.pack();
        frame2.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame2.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```